# add additional echo in if statement

Tags: php

I have this following snippet:

```
        <?php 
        if($people->num_rows >= 1) {
            while($person = $people->fetch_object()) { 
                echo '
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <div class="card card-user">
                        <div class="content">
                            <div class="author">
                                <a href="'.$system->getDomain()?>/user/<?=$person->id.'">
                                    <img class="avatar" src="'.$system->getProfilePicture($person).'">
                                    <h4 class="title">'.$system->getFirstName($person->full_name).', '.$person->age.'</h4> 
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <p class="text-center text-muted">
                                ';
                                echo $person->city.$system->ifComma($person->city); echo ' '.$person->country.'
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                </div>
                ';
            } 
        } else { 
            ?>
```

however next to the actual age (after the closing H4 tag) I'd like to add a further function which shows the current online status of the user.

The code for this would be as follows:

```
    <?php if($system->isOnline($profile->last_active)) { echo '<i class="online-status online"></i>'; } else { echo '<i class="online-status offline"></i>'; } ?>
```

What is the best way to combine this snippet (online status) with the statement above?

Some expert help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: The best way is to make your HTML and PHP different and then try.. It will be more easy to you...

Comment: Use this `( $system->isOnline($profile->last_active) ? '<i class="online-status online"></i>' : '<i class="online-status offline"></i>' )`  It is a ternary statement, if  `$system->isOnline($profile->last_active)` is true print the first after the ? if not then print the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separate your HTML and PHP code and do it like the below. Your requirement is done using a single line ternary operator.

```
<?php 
if($people->num_rows >= 1) {
    while($person = $people->fetch_object()) { ?>
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
            <div class="card card-user">
                <div class="content">
                    <div class="author">
                        <a href="<?php echo $system->getDomain().'/user/'.$person->id;?>">
                            <img class="avatar" src="<?php echo $system->getProfilePicture($person);?>">
                            <h4 class="title"><?php echo $system->getFirstName($person->full_name).', '.$person->age;?></h4> 
                            <?php echo ($system->isOnline($profile->last_active)) ? '<i class="online-status online"></i>' : '<i class="online-status offline"></i>'; ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <p class="text-center text-muted">
                        <?php echo $person->city.$system->ifComma($person->city); echo ' '.$person->country;?>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div> 
        </div>      
    <?php 
    } 
}
?>
```